# Get name of .bdf font using Freetype

Tags: c++, freetype, freetype2

I tried to receive the font name of a `.bdf` font. I am already using Freetype with bdf to render, so this works fine. However, I need to know the font name of the currently used `FT_Face`.

What I tried:

```
BDF_Property bdfProp;
FT_Get_BDF_Property(m_face, "FONT",bdfProp);
std::cout << "BDF Prop Type: " << bdfProp->type << std::endl;
```

This only returns "0", so it doesn't recognize the name tag inside the bdf-file (which is declared as `FONT` inside the bdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
BDF_PropertyRec rec;
FT_Get_BDF_Property(m_face, "FAMILY", &rec);
```

The problem was BDF_Property, because this actually is a pointer not object. So I had a pointer with datatype before, which didn't have any memory allocated.
Now I just do a call-by-reference to the PropertyRec-object itself. Works like it should ;)

Comment: Forgot to mention: The function FT_Get_Property is only able to search inside the STARTPROPERTIES...ENDPROPERTIES section of the bdf font. It is not standard to have a family tag there, like I have in mine. I added that "FAMILY"-tag plus Family-name myself, because this function is not able to read the common "FONT"-tag at the very start of a bdf font. just so you know.